# Segmentation Fault while loading "big" texture file

Tags: c++, c, opengl, segmentation-fault, texture-mapping

For my OpenGL project I'm doing txture mapping. If I load 1000 kb tga file there is no problem, but when I try to load 3000 kb tga file I get segmentation fault at his line:

```
    tgaFile.data = new unsigned char[imageSize];
```

Then I tried to load BMP file. I get segmentation fault at this line:

```
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    GL_RGBA,
    image->width,
    image->height,
    0,
    GL_RGBA,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    image->pixels); //at this line I get segmentation fault
```

Then I resize my BMP file 512*512 to 256*256. Then the problem solved. But I want to load also big files. What is the problem? How can I solve this? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Wİndows 8.

I'm initializing image like:

```
Image* image = loadBMP("yer.bmp");
```

Also loadBMP function:

> ```
> Image* loadBMP(const char* filename) {
> ifstream input;
> input.open(filename, ifstream::binary);
> assert(!input.fail() || !"Could not find file");
> char buffer[2];
> input.read(buffer, 2);
> assert(buffer[0] == 'B' && buffer[1] == 'M' || !"Not a bitmap file");
> input.ignore(8);
> int dataOffset = readInt(input);
> //Read the header
> int headerSize = readInt(input);
> int width;
> int height;
> switch (headerSize) {
> case 40:
>     //V3
>     width = readInt(input);
>     height = readInt(input);
>     input.ignore(2);
>     assert(readShort(input) == 24 || !"Image is not 24 bits per pixel");
>     assert(readShort(input) == 0 || !"Image is compressed");
>     break;
> case 12:
>     //OS/2 V1
>     width = readShort(input);
>     height = readShort(input);
>     input.ignore(2);
>     assert(readShort(input) == 24 || !"Image is not 24 bits per pixel");
>     break;
> case 64:
>     //OS/2 V2
>     assert(!"Can't load OS/2 V2 bitmaps");
>     break;
> case 108:
>     //Windows V4
>     assert(!"Can't load Windows V4 bitmaps");
>     break;
> case 124:
>     //Windows V5
>     assert(!"Can't load Windows V5 bitmaps");
>     break;
> default:
>     assert(!"Unknown bitmap format");
> }
> //Read the data
> int bytesPerRow = ((width * 3 + 3) / 4) * 4 - (width * 3 % 4);
> int size = bytesPerRow * height;
> auto_array<char> pixels(new char[size]);
> input.seekg(dataOffset, ios_base::beg);
> input.read(pixels.get(), size);
> //Get the data into the right format
> auto_array<char> pixels2(new char[width * height * 3]);
> for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
>     for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
>         for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
>             pixels2[3 * (width * y + x) + c] =
>                 pixels[bytesPerRow * y + 3 * x + (2 - c)];
>         }
>     }
> }
> input.close();
> return new Image(pixels2.release(), width, height);
> ```
>
> }

And loadTGA function:

```
bool loadTGA(const char *filename, STGA& tgaFile)
{
FILE *file;
unsigned char type[4];
unsigned char info[6];

    file = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (!file)
    return false;

fread (&type, sizeof (char), 3, file);
fseek (file, 12, SEEK_SET);
fread (&info, sizeof (char), 6, file);

//image type either 2 (color) or 3 (greyscale)
if (type[1] != 0 || (type[2] != 2 && type[2] != 3))
{
    fclose(file);
    return false;
}

tgaFile.width = info[0] + info[1] * 256;
tgaFile.height = info[2] + info[3] * 256;
tgaFile.byteCount = info[4] / 8;

if (tgaFile.byteCount != 3 && tgaFile.byteCount != 4) {
    fclose(file);
    return false;
}

long imageSize = tgaFile.width * tgaFile.height
 * tgaFile.width * tgaFile.byteCount;

//allocate memory for image data
tgaFile.data = new unsigned char[imageSize];

//read in image data
fread(tgaFile.data, sizeof(unsigned char), imageSize, file);

//close file
fclose(file);

return true;
}
```

Comment: How are you initializing `image` and `tgaFile`? What is `imageSize`? There isn't nearly enough information in your question.

Comment: Step through the program with the debugger and have a look at `image` right before the call to `glTexImage2D `.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. The problem is since I am using RGBA as internal format I am telling opengl to use 4 bytes per pixel. However it is actually 3.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
0,
GL_RGBA,
image->width,
image->height,
0,
GL_RGB,//The change is here
GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
image->pixels);
```

When I made this change, it worked.